# Monoidal category of irreducible highest weight modules of the Virasoro algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, lie-algebras, monoidal-categories, conformal-field-theory

I'm trying to see if I can construct a monoidal category $\mathbf{C}$ whose objects are the irreducible unitary highest weight representations of the Virasoro algebra.

I am thinking on doing the following, which seems quite natural: start with the category $\mathbf{Rep}(Vir)$ and let $\mathbf{C}$ the full subcategory whose objects are the irreducible unitary highest weight representations.

But now if we take the tensor product to be the usual tensor product of representations of a Lie algebra, then the tensor product of two objects of $\mathbf{C}$ may be reducible in general, and thus the category is not monoidal. (This is my only issue, since the tensor product of arrows will be trivially in $\mathbf{C}$ because this subcategory is full, and also $\mathbf{1}$ (the unit of the monoidal category $\mathbf{Rep}(Vir)$) is in $\mathbf C$).

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what do you want, but usually the irreducible representations of some $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponds to the *simple* objects of $Rep(\mathfrak{g})$. So the tensor product of two simple objects is still an object of $Rep(\mathfrak{g})$. Now the monoidal category structure for such representations of $Vir$ was studied (in the Connes fusion framework) in the [thesis of Terence Loke](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=127514) (and in mine for $Vir_{1/2}$). They are tensor product of $Rep$ of some loop algebras.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux This seems helpful, thank you. The link you provided does not contain the thesis itself, and I did not find it online. Is there a place where I can find the document?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I did find your thesis, though. But on a first skim I only found comments about the category for the case of loop algebras, not the Virasoro algebra. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: You will find a scan of Loke's thesis in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17mMlzPypMZSWGCROMwEyq-7-foRIZBzF). About [mine](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00514234/document), see Recall 12.39 and Theorem 12.46.

Comment: and *yes*, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/144572/34538) should also help.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I now realized that in your first comment you referred something that is probably my biggest concern: the tensor product of two irreducible representations will not be irreducible in general, as I wrote in  my question. So I want a "new tensor product" for which the product of irreps is still an irrep. Do you know if that Connes fusion product has this property?

Comment: No, it has not this property. But what is your motivation for such a property? If the tensor product of two irreps is still an irrep then the Perron-Frobenius dimension of every irrep should be $1$, and then the fusion category should be pointed (i.e. a deformation of a group), isn't it? What I wrote is for fusion categories; for the more general framework of monoidal categories, some confirmations are required...

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux My motivation comes from physics (long story), since there is another monoidal category which is conjectured to be related to this category of irreps.
(I do not know about that Perron-Frobenius dimension). I am a physicist with not that much (maybe not enough) knowledge about tensor categories the like)

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius-Perron+dimension